# What's wrong with CascadeClassifier (opencv) that is called many time

Tags: c++, opencv

Assume:

1. There are N files on disk that require face detection.
2. If I do it in "slow" mode all is well (faces are faces at their rects):

   ```
   for(auto mat : getMyMats()) {
      CascadeClassifier facer("haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml");
      vector<Rect> faces;
      facer.detectMultiScale(mat, faces);
   }
   ```
3. But if i try to cache and reuse CascadeClassifier - near by 50% image are detected very wrong - invalid place, size, count of faces:

   ```
   CascadeClassifier facer("haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml");
   for(auto mat : getMyMats()) {   
       vector<Rect> faces;
       facer.detectMultiScale(mat, faces);
    }
   ```

What's wrong with CascadeClassifier reusing
Windows, OpenCV 3.0 both debug and release build.

SAMPLE CODE TO REPRODUCE:

```
 // compiler - opencv/include referenced
    // linker - opencv/lib referenced and 
    // opencv_core300.lib, opencv_imgproc300.lib, opencv_imgcodecs300.lib, opencv_objdetect300.lib (or world or debug libs) are referenced
    // 1.png, 2.png, 3.png, 

    #include <vector>
    #include <string>
    #include <iostream>
    #include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"

    using namespace cv;
    using namespace std;


    //count faces in load-every-time call
    int no_reuse_call() {
        int cnt = 0;
        for (auto n : { "1.png","2.png","3.png" }) {
            vector<Rect> faces{};
            CascadeClassifier facer("haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml");
            Mat m = imread(n, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
            facer.detectMultiScale(m, faces, 1.1, 3, CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(50, 50));
            cnt += faces.size(); //vector given to detectMultiScale cleared in detectMultiScale
            cout << faces[0] << endl;
        }
        for (auto n : { "1.png","2.png","3.png" }) {
            vector<Rect> faces{};
            CascadeClassifier facer("haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml");
            Mat m = imread(n, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
            facer.detectMultiScale(m, faces, 1.1, 3, CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(50, 50));
            cnt += faces.size(); //vector given to detectMultiScale cleared in detectMultiScale
            cout << faces[0] << endl;
        }
        return cnt;
    }

    //coutn faces in one-instance call
    int reuse_call() {
        int cnt = 0;
        CascadeClassifier facer("haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml");
        for (auto n : { "1.png","2.png","3.png" }) {
            vector<Rect> faces{};
            Mat m = imread(n, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
            facer.detectMultiScale(m, faces, 1.1, 3, CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(50, 50));
            cnt += faces.size(); //vector given to detectMultiScale cleared in detectMultiScale
            cout << faces[0] << endl;
        }
        for (auto n : { "1.png","2.png","3.png" }) {
            vector<Rect> faces{};
            Mat m = imread(n, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
            facer.detectMultiScale(m, faces, 1.1, 3, CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(50, 50));
            cnt += faces.size(); //vector given to detectMultiScale cleared in detectMultiScale
            cout << faces[0] << endl;
        }
        return cnt;
    }

    int reuse_call_reverse() {
        int cnt = 0;
        CascadeClassifier facer("haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml");
        for (auto n : {"3.png" ,"2.png", "1.png"}) {
            vector<Rect> faces{};
            Mat m = imread(n, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
            facer.detectMultiScale(m, faces, 1.1, 3, CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(50, 50));
            cnt += faces.size(); //vector given to detectMultiScale cleared in detectMultiScale
            cout << faces[0] << endl;
        }
        for (auto n : { "3.png" ,"2.png", "1.png" }) {
            vector<Rect> faces{};
            Mat m = imread(n, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
            facer.detectMultiScale(m, faces, 1.1, 3, CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(50, 50));
            cnt += faces.size(); //vector given to detectMultiScale cleared in detectMultiScale
            cout << faces[0] << endl;
        }
        return cnt;
    }

    int main() {
        cout << "Created every image 2*3 files" << endl;
        cout << no_reuse_call() << endl;
        cout << "Created one time and files in alphabet order 2*3 files" <<  endl;
        cout << reuse_call() << endl;
        cout << "Created one time and files in contra - alphabet order 2*3 files" << endl;
        cout << reuse_call_reverse() << endl;
        cout << "You can see:" << endl;
        cout << "   if cascade is reused - detection in 3.png file is stabily wrong if it is processed after 1.png and 2.png" << endl;
        cout << "   it's depend on order - if 3.png is first in row it detected right even in second call after 1.png and 2.png" << endl;
        cout << "   it's random and based somehow on image - 1.png and 2.png are always detected validly" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: in your provided code you don't actually use `faces` so it will unused get cleared after each iteration. How do you REALLY use it? Do you make sure that previously detected faces aren't still present for the next image?

Comment: I store them in satelite file in JSON format. How they can be "still in image"?  Every call is against distinct Mat(s) loaded from distinct files.

Comment: in your sample code, `vector<Rect> faces;` is declared locally in the block, so in your sample code `faces` vector will be "cleared" in each iteration, but since you don't use faces vector in your sample code for anything, nobody here knows whether you might have to `.clear` your faces vector manually after usage (which could explain false positive detections).

Comment: can you create a minimal `compilable` sample code so we can reproduce the problem? e.g. load 2 fixed images, store them in a list or vector, then run your for-loop and display the images.

Comment: SAMPLE IMAGES:


[![non-problem image 1 (required to reproduce)][1]][1]
[![non-problem image 2 (required to reproduce)][2]][2]
[![image where problem is detected][3]][3]

COMPILABLE SAMPLE IS GIVEN IN MAIN MESSAGE, HERE YOU CAN GET IMAGES TO REPRODUCE
[1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/P6EvW.jpg
[2]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/sjP10.jpg
[3]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/LRrXY.jpg

Comment: save images as 1.png, 2.png, 3.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91771/discussion-between---and-micka).

Comment: for OpenCV 2.4x this code (had to change `auto:` loop though) works as intended. So maybe a bug in OpenCV 3

Comment: have posted issue to opencv github

Answer (score 0):

Look at https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/issues/5475

due to some reasones ocl in opencv 3.0.0 is not (stable?)
so author recomend to call setUseOpenCL(false); in programm - with this option all work well